# Android WebView geolocation not working

Tags: android, webview, geolocation

My application is displaying a `WebView` which is requesting for user's geolocation. The `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` callback in my `WebChromeClient` is called, but the JS callback is never called in response. Here's my Java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Binding views…

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

    webview.loadUrl(BASE_URL);
}

private class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    @DebugLog
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        callback.invoke(origin, true, true);
    }
}
```

As expected, `onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt` is called once, the first time the web page requests for user's position, then isn't called anymore. But either on the first or the following position requests, the JS callback is never called.

Edit: I just tested with an other application requesting the position in background. It worked. My application hass the following permissions (I'm pretty sure most of them are useless for this, but…):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: include gps permissions and ensure gps is ON.

Comment: GPS is on and works for other applications like Google Maps. I added the relevant permissions to the question.

Comment: Did you solve the question. I have the same problem

Comment: @ArdaKazancı Sorry, I'm not working on this project anymore. I don't know how it has been solve - if it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true : onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt is called once, the first time the web page requests for user's location, then it's not called anymore. 
I am also facing the same issue. One workaround could be reload the page after location permission is granted.